# Python conditional Suggestion

Tags: python-3.x, variables, conditional-statements

Are there solutions which permit to say in Python:

**if** X isn't used: I use it

**else**: I don't use X => I will use another variable X1

Thanks a lot,

Antoine

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a variable is defined locally using:

```
'X' in locals()
```

Eg:

```
>>> 'testVariable' in locals()
False
>>> testVariable = 35
>>> 'testVariable' in locals()
True
```

If you want to check if it's defined globally, you can use `globals()` instead of `locals()`.